# Android - how to tell/set which API Level is targeted

Tags: java, android, ant, titanium

well..kind of new to Android, using ant to build something I downloaded.

how can I tell which API level is target ? I saw nothing about it in the build.xml file ..

when I try to use classes from API Level 8, I am getting symbol not found errors..

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have

```
<uses-sdk
    android:targetSdkVersion="4"
    android:minSdkVersion="3" />
```

in the AndroidManifest.xml

But if you are working with eclipse, you have to check that the jar file in Google APIs is correct. If you just change that number, and still use the old jar files, you will get the same errors.

you can change that in project > properties > android, and choose the api you want

Comment: as I wrote below.. there is no manifest file... just build.xml. I am trying to build (successfully) and alter with API level 8 code the Titanium mobile library (fail) github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile

Comment: If there is no manifest then your files are corrupted or you didn't download an Android project. All android source projects have a manifest xml file.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify it in the Android Manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

You can also check the `default.properties` file are the root of your project. It contains a line

```
target=android-8
```

Comment: there is no manifest file, and no default.properties files... just build.xml. I am trying to build (successfully) and alter with API level 8 code the Titanium mobile library (fail) https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile